# Compare the attributes in the two similar XPaths

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, comparison

XML:

```
    <Emp id= "1">
    <EmpAdd num = "1">
        <Add city  = "Brentwood" c2 = "TN" c3 = "US" c4 = "37027" c5="" c6=""/>
    </EmpAdd>
    <List>
        <Emp id= "1">
            <EmpAdd num = "1">
                <Add city  = "Oswego" c2 = "TN" c3 = "US"  c7=""/>
            </EmpAdd>
        </Emp>
    </List>
</Emp>
```

I want to compare the attributes in the two XPaths that have same Element names
"Emp/EmpAdd/Add" and "List/Emp/EmpAdd/Add". The attribute numbers is not same in both XPaths.

Also based on that add a new attribute IsModified in Emp/List/Emp/@IsModified and set the value as 'Y' if any of the compared(city, c2, c3)attributes value differ else 'N'.
I have tried with this but it is not working as expected.

After the transformation I want:

```
<Emp id="1">
   <EmpAdd num="1">
      <Add city="Brentwood" c2="TN" c3="US" c4="37027" c5="" c6=""/>
   </EmpAdd>
   <List>
      <Emp id="1" IsModified="Y"/>
   </List>
</Emp>
```

but I am getting "N" in the output.

XSLT code tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 

 <xsl:template match = "List/Emp/EmpAdd">

 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="((Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@City != List/Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@City)
    or  (Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@C2!= List/Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@C2)
    or (Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@C3 != List/Emp/EmpAdd/Add/@C3)) ">
    <xsl:attribute name="IsModified">Y</xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:attribute name="IsModified">N</xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not well-versed with XSLT. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of an attribute is `city` then your XPath needs to be `@city` and not `@City`. The same for the other attribute names.

And of course, in the context of a certain node like that matched element `EmpAdd`, you need paths relative to that element:

```
<xsl:template match = "List/Emp/EmpAdd">
 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="((../../../EmpAdd/Add/@city != Add/@city)
    or  (../../../EmpAdd/Add/@c2!= Add/@c2)
    or (../../../EmpAdd/Add/@c3 != Add/@c3)) ">
    <xsl:attribute name="IsModified">Y</xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:attribute name="IsModified">N</xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```